# Magento Navigation

Tags: magento, content-management-system, e-commerce

I'm using Magento Go and have only just started with it, I'm already stuck! How do I add a contact page, home page and an about us page to the main navigation!?

Comment: Magento Go, Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a limitation in Magento Go, among quite a few others. There is a workaround, but no system-defined method for doing this that I am aware of.

**The Workaround:**

Create a static block in the CMS, and there use widgets to define the links to each CMS/Category page. Add the static block to the location where you would like it to be displayed. You will have to manually update the static block each time you want to include or change a link. We have done this, and yes, it is a pain, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the section from the Magento Go wiki about adding CMS pages to the main navigation.  It uses Magento's built in URL Redirect Manager which is really handy to know about if you are doing Magento work.

http://go.magento.co.uk/support/kb/entry/name/adding-page-links-in-the-navigation-bar/

EDIT - Actually that might be redirecting me to the UK domain so that url may not necessarily work for you depending on where you are. Just enter 'adding page links to main navigation' in the Magento Go search form and it will give you the info on this.

Comment: Or just use http://go.magento.com/support/kb/entry/name/adding-page-links-in-the-navigation-bar/

Answer (score 0):

For Contact page you can create:

```
url < a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()?>contacts">Contact</a>
```

And next About us:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl()?>about us">
```